# MySQL group-by with comma-seperated list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following data

```
id category_id bookmark_id
1      1           1
2      2           1
3      3           1
4      4           2
5      5           1
```

and mysql query is

```
SELECT * from table_name group by bookmark_id
```

it returns

```
id category_id   bookmark_id
1     1             1
4     4             2
```

which is fine

But i want one more colum extra

```
id category_id category_list bookmark_id
1    1           1,2,3,5         1
4    4             4             2
```

Any idea how to achieve above result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select min(category_id) as min_cat, 
       group_concat(distinct category_id order by category_id) as category_list, 
       bookmark_id
from your_table
group by bookmark_id
```

Comment: what is the purpose of min(category_id) as min_cat,

Comment: It returns the first `category_id` for every `bookmark_id`